# Adding checks to Large SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the query:

```
SELECT tbl_product.id, tbl_productspecification.id AS specificationId,
            tbl_product.ProductId, tbl_seller.CompanyName, tbl_product.ProductName, tbl_product.Description, mst_Categories.id AS 'Category',
            tbl_productspecification.RetailPrice, tbl_productspecification.SalePrice,
            tbl_product.image, tbl_productspecification.Discount, tbl_product.EndTime, tbl_product.Seller_Id
            FROM tbl_product
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_seller ON tbl_seller.SelId = tbl_product.Seller_Id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN mst_Categories ON (mst_Categories.id = tbl_product.Category OR mst_Categories.id = tbl_product.SubCategory)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_productspecification ON tbl_productspecification.ProductId = tbl_product.ProductId
            LEFT OUTER JOIN mst_image ON mst_image.Product = tbl_product.ProductId
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_dealinterest ON tbl_dealinterest.ProductId = tbl_product.ProductId
            where tbl_product.Active='y' and tbl_product.StartTime <= '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' and tbl_product.EndTime>'".date("Y-m-d")." 06:00:00'
            ".$subquery." ".$groupby;
```

The `tbl_dealinterest` table has a few fields:

```
[BuyerId] [ProductId] [Active]
```

I need to filter out any records are in `tbl_dealinterest` that match `[BuyerId]` `[ProductId]` and `[Active]` does not equal `n`

I have tried a few things but not all the products are listed `tbl_dealinterest`.  Only when someone chooses an option does it get entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should filter out any matching records in tbl_dealinterest.  This is assuming that tbl_dealinterest.BuyerId would never be NULL if a record existed.

The left join to the tbl_dealinterest table will return NULL values for all of the fields in the tbl_dealinterest table if there is no match.  The "tbl_dealinterest.BuyerId IS NULL" in the where clause will filter out the matches.

```
SELECT tbl_product.id, tbl_productspecification.id AS specificationId,
            tbl_product.ProductId, tbl_seller.CompanyName, tbl_product.ProductName, tbl_product.Description, mst_Categories.id AS 'Category',
            tbl_productspecification.RetailPrice, tbl_productspecification.SalePrice,
            tbl_product.image, tbl_productspecification.Discount, tbl_product.EndTime, tbl_product.Seller_Id
            FROM tbl_product
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_seller ON tbl_seller.SelId = tbl_product.Seller_Id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN mst_Categories ON (mst_Categories.id = tbl_product.Category OR mst_Categories.id = tbl_product.SubCategory)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_productspecification ON tbl_productspecification.ProductId = tbl_product.ProductId
            LEFT OUTER JOIN mst_image ON mst_image.Product = tbl_product.ProductId
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_dealinterest ON tbl_dealinterest.BuyerId = tbl_product.BuyerId AND tbl_dealinterest.ProductId = tbl_product.ProductId AND tbl_dealinterest.active <> 'n'
            where tbl_product.Active='y' and tbl_product.StartTime <= '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' and tbl_product.EndTime>'".date("Y-m-d")." 06:00:00'
            AND tbl_dealinterest.BuyerId IS NULL
            ".$subquery." ".$groupby;
```